# Taking notes as a mathematics student

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning

a couple of years back I was in class with a  student that was copying notes in class from the whiteboard and after class he would make his own notes out of the already written notes (he would somehow rewrite them). On theoretical tests (tests where they tested knowledge of theorems definitions and proofs of them) he always got 100 % marks. I have lost connection with this student, so I want to ask this community, those of you who make their own notes(after copying from the whiteboard) how do you make them(what information do you rewrite). I know that this is a personal preference, but I want to try this approach and see how it goes.

Comment: I think rewriting helps me understand better - working on the material again reinforces what I learned in class. I can add comments or notes by the side to follow the reasoning.

Comment: I would second what @P.J. said: I don;t have time in class to _understand_ in full what is written, only take notes. Rewriting helps me think in my own time about what is written. I try to write my notes as if I was trying to explain the concepts to someone else in class or someone who hadn't done the subject - it gets me asking a lot of questions that I wish I would have asked in class! And plenty of examples - and especially counterexamples - I find crucial

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I very much like to rewrite the teacher's notes using the following approach. I rewrite all the definitions and propositions on two different sheets of paper. This allows me to focus first on definitions (as in a play, the characters are introduced from the beginning). And when I master them all, I can start reading the propositions and theorems. What I find most important in a course is not the theorems and propositions, but the definitions, without them it's impossible to understand something in math.